# Weird flashing vertices when a mesh becomes higher poly

Tags: modeling

Whenever I have a low poly object I have no issues. When I try and make an object with a higher number of vertices I start to get weird graphical glitches in edit mode, with many of the vertices flashing as I move around the object. As far as I can tell, it's not having any permanent effect on the model, but it's extremely annoying to put up with while modelling!

Does anyone know what is causing this?

[image]

Comment: Looks like z-fighting. See if there's another sphere object in the same spot where the one you edit is located (you can hide some vertices of the currently selected sphere to look behind it or go to Object mode and hide this one).

Comment: @MrZak It's definitely not z-fighting. I get this whenever I apply a subdivision surface modifier to an object, or if I add a high poly mesh.

Comment: Z-fighting occurs not only when there are 2 objects in the same place. Open N panel in the viewport > View tab and change clipping values of the viewport camera to decrease the difference between Clip End and Start. Something like 0,01m and 100m would be fine for that scene. Other than that it might be a problem with Blender using GPU to redraw the textured viewport.